# Hyphenation in Jinja template (using Django Wagtail)

Tags: django, templates, jinja2, hyphenation

I have a Django Wagtail application, which employs the templating machine Jinja (or Jinja2, not entirely sure, but won't make a difference for this issue).

When I e.g. want to use the templating to show the title of a blog post, I can write

```
{{ post.title }}
```

This works perfectly fine. But I cannot enforce hyphenation in this title. If the title holds a very long word, this crashes my layout on small devices. Anyone an idea how I can tell Jinja that hyphenation should be enabled?

Comment: Hyphenation isn't something you would ordinarily do at template level, as the template has no knowledge of screen size - you probably want to do this [in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens) instead.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify this earlier... of course I tried using CSS, namely the hyphens property. But the CSS has no effect on the template content.